# Format Excel datetimes with fixed widths and typical software formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, date-time, utc

How can Excel be used to format dates with fixed widths using formats typical to software applications (MySQL DATETIME format, ISO 8601, RFC3339)?  While it would be "nice" to convert to UTC, I am only interested right now about the format appearance.

```
7/27/2017  2:11:18 PM (Given)
2017-07-26 14:11:18 (MySQL DATETIME format)
2017-07-27T18:13:12+00:00 (ISO 8601)
```

Comment: Set a Custom format of: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.  Off the top of my head, I'm not sure how to get 24-hour time format, but I know it can be done

Comment: @Bandersnatch - In Excel, I believe you just have to capitalize `hh`: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`.